# Filter out columns using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I need to filter my data structure for generating a chart using underscore.js.

`var data = [
  ["Name", "Class", "Rollno", "Subject"],
  ["Anil", "10", "112121212", "BAS"],
  ["Sunil", "10", "112121212", "BAS"]
];`

1. My data structure consists of a list of rows.
2. The first row contains the labels for each column.
3. The following rows contain the values for the chart.

So if in this case I pass `Name` as a key the filter should remove only the first column. Furthermore I would like to pass in a list of column names in order to remove multiple columns from my data structure.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) provides "useful functional programming helpers" and is a great library to program JavaScript in a more functional way. Some of the methods may already be contained in modern JavaScript.

The code uses the following underscore methods: [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each), [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains)

The following works for a single column.

```
// Find the column index within the first row of the dataset 
// using the given column name. This index will later be used in
// the filter.
//
// Take care, indexOf will return -1 if the column name was not found
// which would be a invalid index
var index = data[0].indexOf("Name"); 

// Generate a new dataset by collecting the filtered rows
// The input to the mapping function is each row.
var withoutColumn = _.map(data, function (row) {

    // Apply a filter on each element in the row;
    // The second parameter to the filter function is the current index 
    // of the element within the row.
    return _.filter(row, function (r, idx) {

        // Return true if the current index idx does not match the  
        // preselected index. This effectively removes the selected
        // column.
        return idx !== index;
    });
});
```

Now lets extend this for many columns:

a) Get a list of all indexes of columns to be removed.

b) Adopt test method in the filter to check if the current index is within the list of previously found indexes.

```
function removeColumnsByName(data, columnNames) {

    // Collect the index of each given column name in the array indexes
    var indexes = [];

    // Iterate over the column names
    _.each(data[0], function(column, idx) {

        // If the current column name is contained in the given column 
        // names store its index idx in indexes.
        if (_.contains(columnNames, column)) {
            indexes.push(idx);
        } 

    });

    // Again collect the filtered rows using a different filter function
    return _.map(data, function (row) {
        return _.filter(row, function (r, idx) {

            // Modified test: return true if the current index idx is not 
            // contained in the list of indexes
            return ! _.contains(indexes, idx);
        });
    });
}

console.log (removeColumnsByName(data, ["Name", "Subject"]));
```

To remove rows by the column name you could use the following method:

```
function filterByName (data, name) {
    return _.filter(data, function (entry) { 
        return entry[0] !== name; 
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please rephrase your question, maybe I did not understand it correctly. If you call `filterByName(data, "Anil")`, data taken from the question, the entry with name "Anil" will get filtered out.

Comment: and looks like it's only take single argument.

Comment: filterByName(data, ["Name", "Class"]) << This should remove both index from all the nested array.

Comment: I agree, question is not clear. Please provide desired output, maybe it will clear things out..

Comment: Hey @obey , you understand correctly but the only thing is it should be random index .

Comment: Thanks for help @chriopp but not sure how it's work with multiple index ?

Comment: Superb :) Thanks a lot .. you save my day thank you very much

Comment: It's great if you add some comment just to explain how it's working :)

Comment: @Anil Yadav Done.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to have output like this? :

```
[
  ["Class","Rollno","Subject"], 
  [ "10", "112121212","BAS"],
  [ "10", "112121212","BAS"]
]
```

Try to do:

```
data.forEach(item => item.splice(0))
```

If you want to do so for any column, use:

```
data.forEach(item => item.splice(n))  // n is column index (zero based)
```

Comment: If possible to you please share a running example with random index.

Comment: should be `data.forEach(item => item.splice(1))`, right?

Comment: @AnilYadav i updated the response. @ chiropp yep, you are right

Comment: It's remove everything and keep only one array